# Error handling in cljc macro

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I found it surprisingly tricky to define a macro to do error handling in both **clj** and **cljs**. I assumed it was a simple matter of swapping `Exception` with `js/Error`, but it turned out to be more complicated than that.

At first, I tried this:

```
(defmacro my-macro
  [& forms]
 `(try
    ~@forms
    (catch #?(:clj Exception :cljs js/Error) e#
      ,,,)))
```

But this produced `Exception` every time. I soon realized that the problem was that the macro was being called during the compilation of my **cljs** files, which happens in a **clj** environment. Therefore, I would have to have the macro return a form that would resolve to the correct exception class at runtime. I tried this:

```
(def exception-class
  #?(:clj Exception :cljs js/Error))

(defmacro my-macro
  [& forms]
 `(try
    ~@forms
    (catch exception-class e#
      ,,,)))
```

Now it worked in **cljs**, but not in **clj**!!! After some experimentation, I discovered that JVM Clojure (apparently) does not allow you to refer to the exception class indirectly. You have to refer to `Exception` directly by name.

So finally, I settled on this:

```
(def fake-java
  #?(:cljs (clj->js {:lang {:Exception js/Error}})))

(defmacro my-macro
  [& forms]
 `(let [~'java fake-java]
    (try
      ~@forms
      (catch Exception e#
        ,,,))))
```

`Exception` expands to `java.lang.Exception`, which now resolves to the correct exception class at runtime in both **clj** and **cljs**.

My question is, is there a better way to this? And why does JVM Clojure not allow referring to the exception class indirectly, but ClojureScript does?

**Update**

With ClojureMostly's help, I have refactored the macro like this, and it works:

```
(defmacro my-macro
  [& forms]
 `(try
    ~@forms
    (catch ~(if (:ns &env) 'js/Error 'Exception) e#
      ,,,)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common way to do this is to [check for the `:ns` key](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clojurescript/iBY5HaQda4A/w1lAQi9_AwsJ) in the special `&env` binding that you have in a `defmacro`. [Copied from `plumatic/schema`](https://github.com/plumatic/schema/blob/78cf0d21b8886ee2000e28b83b5027c4ae842a17/src/clj/schema/macros.clj):

```
(defn cljs-env?
  "Take the &env from a macro, and tell whether we are expanding into cljs."
  [env]
  (boolean (:ns env)))

(defmacro try-catchall
  "A cross-platform variant of try-catch that catches all exceptions.
   Does not (yet) support finally, and does not need or want an exception class."
  [& body]
  (let [try-body (butlast body)
        [catch sym & catch-body :as catch-form] (last body)]
    (assert (= catch 'catch))
    (assert (symbol? sym))
    (if (cljs-env? &env)
      `(try ~@try-body (~'catch js/Object ~sym ~@catch-body))
      `(try ~@try-body (~'catch Throwable ~sym ~@catch-body)))))
```

Usage:

```
(macros/try-catchall (f)  (catch e# ::exception))
```

Comment: You left out the definition of `if-cljs`, which is the most important part!  Also, what they're doing here is returning a completely different try/catch form depending on the environment, which isn't what I wanted to do.  However, with some tweaking, `(:ns &env)` does exactly what I need it to. I'll update my question with the new code.

Comment: I suppose that (checking for `:ns` key in `&env`) works today, and might even work tomorrow.  But there's absolutely no guarantee it will work.  If you implement this solution, it's important to know that you are relying on "undocumented behavior".

Answer (score 4):

You could refactor your macro to be expressed in terms of a function call.  This function would accept a "thunk" of the forms and wrap it in the `try` (rather than doing this directly in the macro).

For example:

```
(defmacro my-macro [& forms]
  `(my-macro* (fn []
                ~@forms)))
```

Then you can define `my-macro*` as:

```
(defn my-macro* [f]
  (try
    (f)
    (catch #?(:clj Exception :cljs js/Error) e
      ...)))
```

Comment: I got so involved in troubleshooting the problem, I didn't even think of this obvious solution! However, ClojureMostly's answer more directly addresses my question, so I accepted it.